# How do I write a query based on a boolean property using EmberFire?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase

I'm using EmberFire from the master branch targeting Ember 2.0.2 and Ember Data 2.0.0 and I'm trying to write a query that filters a list of customers based on whether they are subscribed or not. I have tried the following code to no avail:

Attempt to do this the way adapters probably should work:

```
this.store.query('customer', { isSubscribed: false });
```

Attempt to do this the way EmberFire/Firebase seems to indicate it should be done:

```
this.store.query('customer', { orderBy: 'isSubscribed', equalTo: false });
```

Neither of these work so I'm wondering, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with EmberFire?

Comment: Could you provide requests made?